# Error in debugonce function in Rstudio, it returns - argument must be a function

Tags: r, debugging

I have this code in R but everytime I run the debug function I get the following message

```
makes_poly=function(n,u){
  vec=c(1)
  for ( i in 1:n){
    vec[i+1]= u^i
  }
  return(vec)
}
debugonce(makes_poly(2,4))
```

but everytime I run the debug function I get the following message

```
Error in debugonce(makes_poly(2, 4)) : argument must be a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value from `makes_poly(2,4)` is a vector, so you are essentially running `debugonce(c(1,4,16))`. Try:

```r
debugonce(makes_poly)
```

Comment: Aw yes, silly error!

Comment: If this has worked would you mind marking the answer as correct?

Comment: New to this site - how would I do that